# How to create a Popularity parameter based on hits, likes, dislikes and time

Tags: php, mysql

I got a database with a lot of articles created through time. Now I want my script to modify a "popularity" field in the database based on hits, likes, dislikes and time.

How would you do that? The older the article the less relevant of course. But if the article is two weeks old BUT got a lot of hits and likes I want it to show up even though.

Any ideas?

Comment: please tell us more: do you have all the hits, likes and dislikes in your database? Or you need to fetch some data from the 3rd party source, like Facebook for likes?

Comment: yes I have all of that. No code needed it's more theoretical how you would do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you already have all the data, I would calculate the popularity like follows (in pseudo code):

```
Popularity = (1 / now - time) + likes - dislikes.
```

So in MySQL query it would be something like this:

```
UPDATE articles SET
popularity = (now() - article.timestamp) + article.likes - article.dislikes;
```

After the query is run and the data updated, you could apply the sorting on your data to fetch the most popular artcles:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
ORDER BY popularity DESC.
```

Hope this helps.